# C++ File list with all file informations

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

I'm planning to make a program that would work between a folder on my computer and my NAS. 
It would list all the files in both folders, then determine which file is newer, and then upload it to the other device.
I know how to upload files via FTP, but I'm stuck at the start, because I don't know how to list my files. I have looked a little at using `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` with `WIN32_FIND_DATA`. This way, I can get the last write data, but this doesn't let me list subdirectories.
Do you know any easy way listing all files in a folder and its subdirectory and saving the information of every file in a list?

Comment: I have added the `winapi` tag to this post as it appears you are working specifically with Windows.

Comment: Are you aware of rsync? No need to reinvent the wheel, unless you like inventing wheels ;)

Comment: Why on earth would you want to write yet another backup tool like this yourself? Use rsync, or use one of the N+infinity commercial tools that do exactly this.

Comment: I know I'm reinventing the wheel. But I want to learn to program, so I might as well program something useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` does let you list subdirectories.  One of the members of `WIN32_FIND_DATA` is `dwFileAttributes` which will include `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` for a directory entry.  Simply start another `FindFirstFile()` in that subdirector, rinse, repeat.

There is a sample on MSDN that shows how to use the `FindFirstFile` API, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to use [`boost::recursive_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator).

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctime>

using boost::filesystem::path;
using boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;
using boost::filesystem::directory_entry;
using boost::filesystem::filesystem_error;
using boost::filesystem::last_write_time;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::copy;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::time_t;
using boost::posix_time::from_time_t;

int main(int ac, const char **av)
{
  vector<const char*> args(av+1, av+ac);
  if(args.empty())
    args.push_back(".");
  vector<directory_entry> files;
  BOOST_FOREACH(path p, args)
  {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    copy(recursive_directory_iterator(p, ec),
         recursive_directory_iterator(),
         back_inserter(files));
  }
  BOOST_FOREACH(const directory_entry& d, files)
  {
    if(exists(d.path()))
    {
      cout << from_time_t(last_write_time(d.path())) << " " << d.path() << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```